# How to conditionally add one hot vector to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df
```

It looks as the following when you output it:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   3   2   1
2   2   1   1
```

I need to add 3 new columns, as column "d", column "e", and column "f".
Values in each new column will be determined based on the values of column "b" and column "c".

In a given row:

- If the value of column "b" is bigger than the value of column "c", columns [d, e, f] will have the values [1, 0, 0].
- If the value of column "b" is equal to the value of column "c", columns [d, e, f] will have the values [0, 1, 0].
- If the value of column "b" is smaller than the value of column "c", columns [d, e, f] will have the values [0, 0, 1].

After this operation, the DataFrame needs to look as the following:

```
    a   b   c  d  e  f
0   1   2   3  0  0  1    # Since b smaller than c
1   3   2   1  1  0  0    # Since b bigger than c 
2   2   1   1  0  1  0    # Since b = c
```

My original DataFrame is much bigger than the one in this example.
Is there a good way of doing this in Python without looping through the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply harness the Boolean conditions you've already specified.

```
df["d"] = np.where(df.b >  df.c, 1, 0)
df["e"] = np.where(df.b == df.c, 1, 0)
df["f"] = np.where(df.b <  df.c, 1, 0)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your solution gives the error:  TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>. How can it be solved?

Comment: It can be solved if I test my code, as I'm supposed to ... my apologies ... there's an extra `df` reference ...

Comment: the new solution gives the "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
" error as well. I tried different things but not able to solve the error either.

Comment: Sorry ... I got interrupted during my work ... that was a partial edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.where` to create condition vector and use `str.get_dummies` to create dummies

```
df['vec'] = np.where(df.b>df.c, 'd', np.where(df.b == df.c, 'e', 'f'))
df = df.assign(**df['vec'].str.get_dummies()).drop('vec',1)

    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   1   2   3   0   0   1
1   3   2   1   1   0   0
2   2   1   1   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `np.sign` with `get_dummies`, -1 is c<b,  0 is c=b, 1 is c>b

```
df=df.join(np.sign(df.eval('c-b')).map({-1:'d',0:'e',1:'f'}).astype(str).str.get_dummies())
df
Out[29]: 
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  2  3  0  0  1
1  3  2  1  1  0  0
2  2  1  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Interesting use of np.sign!